# Error convertir varchar en int codeigniter sql server

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación simple  con CodeIgniter y sql 2000, que busca registros según un RUT de cliente, que es de tipo varchar.

modelo:

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Prestaciones_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getHospitalizaciones($rut){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT A.NRO_FI,A.FECHA FROM FICHA A,FIC_PAC B WHERE A.NRO_FI=B.NRO_FI AND B.RUT_NUM='.$rut.' ORDER BY A.FECHA DESC');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

La consulta la ejecuto en el manager de sql server, y si funciona, pero aquí me sale este error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Error de sintaxis al convertir el valor nvarchar
>   '166-97 ' para una columna de tipo de datos int., SQL state 22005 in
>   SQLExecDirect
>
> Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 138
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Prestaciones\application\models\Prestaciones_model.php
>   Line: 7 Function: query
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Prestaciones\application\controllers\Welcome.php
>   Line: 17 Function: getHospitalizaciones
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Prestaciones\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Buscando en la bd  '166-97 ' es un rut de un paciente, que obviamente esta mal, pero con todos los registros varchar de ese tipo me sale el mismo error.
Pero es solo con php ya que probé la misma en c# y si funciona.

Alguna sugerencia para solucionar este error?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función

> result_array

```
function get_info_carpeta($arreglo){
       $sql= "select fechaRegistro,descripcion from carpetas where activo=true and nombreCarpeta='".$arreglo['carpeta']."'";
        $resultado = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $resultado -> result_array();
        }
```

Si estas usando APIs entonces tu función en la API consumiría el modelo de la siguiente forma:

```
function consulta_carpeta_post(){
        $arreglo = array('carpeta'=>$this->post('carpeta'));
        $result = $this->Modelo_busqueda->get_info_carpeta($arreglo);
        $this->response($result);
    }
```

Finalmente tu controlador consumiría la API de la siguiente manera:

```
$carpeta = $this->input->post('carpeta');
//recibido de la vista
        $ruta = $this->config->site_url() . "/api/Busqueda_api/consulta_carpeta";
        $this->curl->create($ruta);
        $this->curl->post(array('carpeta'=> $carpeta));
        $result['carpeta_info'] = json_decode($this->curl->execute());
        if(!is_null($result['carpeta_info']) && $this->session->userdata('tipo')==1){
           $this->load->view('Header');
            $this->load->view('Menu_comprador');
           $this->load->view('InfoCarpeta',$result);
        }else{
           $this->SinRegistros();
        }
```

Si no estás usando APIs REST, entonces tu controlador consumiría directamente el modelo y el resultado lo enviarías a tu vista.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que $rut es un String y no un número, de ser así tienes que poner las comillas de sql quedando la query así:

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT A.NRO_FI,A.FECHA FROM FICHA A,FIC_PAC B WHERE A.NRO_FI=B.NRO_FI AND B.RUT_NUM='$rut' ORDER BY A.FECHA DESC");
```